# If dynamically allocated element used in templated class how can I deallocate or does it deallocate automatically?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

**I have this kind of templated class**

```
template<class T>
class myClass
{
  public:
 .
 myClass(const T & element); 
 .
  private:
    T element;

};
```

and I use dynamically allocated element as T in main

```
struct Node
{
.
.
};
int main()
{
  myClass<Node*> obj(new Node);
}
```

How can I free the space taken by new keyword or is it done automatically when destructor of myClass have been called ?

Comment: Every `new` has to be matched with a `delete` - if your class doesn't do that (e.g.: in a destructor) then you leak the memory

Comment: This freeing is usually done in the destructor of the template class. You may want to explicitly delete or implement the copy constructor and assignment operator, otherwise you may have to add reference counting to track when the `element` is no longer needed and can safely be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to manage memory on your own. Use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

```
template<class T>
class myClass
{
  public: 
    myClass(std::unique_ptr<T> ptr) : element(std::move(ptr)) { }; 
 
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> element;
};
```

And use it like this

```
myClass<Node> obj(std::make_unique<Node>()); // note that I removed the *
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a common question for C++.
Take a look here: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r-resource-management

The CppCoreGuidelines give you a reasonable way on how to deal with memory.
Consider reading for RAII and Smart-Pointers (everything included in CppCoreGuidelines).

Comment: An answer should be self-contained. Posting a link to an off-site resource is not a suitable answer, this should be a comment.